# Template object of different data type than template parameter

Tags: c++

I have a templated class, and I want a member-function takes in an object of that class with any template parameter.  So it should be able to run something like:

```
main(){
     A<double> object1;
     A<double> object2;
     A<int> object3;

     object1.f(object2);
     object1.f(object3);
}
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work because it assumes that the argument must be of the exact same type as the calling object:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    void f(A<T> &a);
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`f` itself needs to be a template, with its own template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    template <typename U>
    void f(A<U>& a);
}
```

When you call `object1.f(object2)`, `f` will be instantiated with `U` = `double`; when you call `object1.f(object3)`, `f` will be instantiated with `U` = `int`.

In both cases `T` = `double` because `object1` is of type `A<double>` and `T` is a template parameter of the class template `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a member function template:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    template <typename U>
    void f(A<U>& a)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> but it doesn't seem to work because it assumes that the argument must be of the exact same type as the calling object:

Of course it does, because that's what you instruct it to do:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    void f(A<T> &a);
}
```

Perhaps you wanted to make `f` a template itself:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    template <typename T1>   //<--- different type
    void f(A<T1> &a);
}
```